# SignalR on AspNetCore - how to add/modify route in runtime

Tags: signalr-hub, asp-net-core-spa-services

I would like to create new routes at runtime. Is there a way to add `MapHubs` during runtime?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question to the SignalR Core developers, and it's not currently possible:

[How to create Hub and new route at run-time using Roslyn scripting?](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2898)

> We don't currently have any built-in support for dynamic discovery of
>   Hubs. The Hubs are discovered once at startup and loaded into the DI
>   container.